# @font-face in CSS....is it ok?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

On my [website](http://www.vitaminjdesign.com), my font family is `Tw Cen MT, Gill Sans, Century Gothic, sans-serif`. Obviouisly, not everyone is going to have *Tw Cen MT*, so I have chosen to try out the `@font-face` method.

Here is my css:

```
@font-face { font-family: Tw Cen MT; src: local("Tw Cen MT"),  url(fonts/TwCenMT.ttf) }
```

A few questions:

1. Will this work in all modern browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and IE8)?
2. I have not yet tested it because I have the font. Does this method work for you when you visit my [homepage](http://www.vitaminjdesign.com)?
3. the font is a large file. Do you experience a long load time when visiting my site?

Thanks so much in advance

Comment: Are you sure you’re allowed to use that font in that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will technically work in the latest versions of all the browsers you mentioned, although there are some "gotchas", especially surrounding IE.  [Here](http://webfonts.info/wiki/index.php?title=@font-face_browser_support) is a link that goes into that in more detail.

The load time visiting your site was brief ( <1 sec ), but I'm not sure what font it actually pulled since I'm not familiar with all the fonts in your stack.

As far as I know, [this](http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/) is the canonical source for @font-face syntax, although I've had problems even with this.

In my experience, the short answer is that although @font-face is technically widely supported, in practice it can be tricky to get right.

Comment: Nick, would love to hear what troubles you had.

Answer (score 2):

From the non-technical perspective, are you sure your font license permits this? Most commercial font makers would be very, **very** upset at their fonts being provided unprotected for download on the internet like that.

Don't go getting yourself sued.

Comment: if the font is available elsewhere for free, do you think it is OK?

http://www.fontyukle.com/en/1,Tw+Cen+MT

Comment: “Random font downloaded from a website” is very likely to be unauthorised, and indeed “Tw Cen MT” is a commercial font from Monotype that you are not supposed to be able to download for free, much less embed in your own site. See http://www.fonts.com/FindFonts/Detail.htm?pid=427641 for the real cost. Proper freely-licensed fonts have proper sites with clear licensing terms.

Answer (score 1):

[These](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/@font-face) [dudes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530757%28VS.85%29.aspx) says it's ok as long as you surround the URL with "doublequotes" and end every line inside the font-face with a semicolon ;

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://browserlab.adobe.com/ for testing it in different browsers. Or, http://litmusapp.com/browser-testing. Hope that helps.